# Rails 4 Render Different Depednding on Location of Form Submission

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, render

My application allows a user to upload some artwork to a specified campaign through the campaigns 'show' view. This allows me to capture the @campaign.id during the upload for association purposes.

Currently, if an error occurs (validation), it renders action: 'edit'.

I know if I update the **render action: 'edit'** => to **render action: 'show'**, the basic level task works, but it also messes with the render action when editing the record itself.

If there a way for me to check if the 'update' is being processed through the 'show' view in order for me to render the show action instead of edit?

```
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @campaign.update(campaign_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @campaign, notice: 'Campaign was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    format.json { render json: @campaign.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

**Campaign Show View**

```
<button class="btn btn-white" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new_creative">
          <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i> Add New Creative
</button>

<%= render 'remoteforms/add_creative_to_campaign' %>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I want to render the 'edit' action if the user is editing a record but want to render the 'show' action if they are uploading through the show view (currently be done through a modal)

Comment: sorry, it looks I misunderstood you. You would like to know from what page the request comes. I think it is impossible to know by standard ways (it is just a put request). I think you can add a parameter to form on modal page. For example send in the request new parameter `modal: true` and check it in action

Comment: another idea is to check `request.referer` in controller

Comment: Added code for reference. My modal forms are retained in a folder outside the campaign folder called remoteforms. Creatives (artwork as I referenced) is a nested element to Campaigns

Comment: in controller when validation is failed you can: 1. check `request.referer` and find out from what page request comes 2. or you can check some parameter (which you pass from modal form). And after this you can decide what you should render in the response